# Regular Expression for (){}[]<>

Tags: regex

I want to restrict these characters in a string. I don't want only the following characters.

```
( ) { } [ ] < >
```

for that I'm trying

```
return !String.valueOf(paramValue).matches("[(){}\\[\\]<>]");
```

Can anybody please tell me how to write regular expression for the same?

Comment: You need to escape some of them. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What regex flavor? Define "restrict".

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: yes.i want to ignore those characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[^(){}\[\]<>]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KCSzdmJFeL6MamRT)

Comment: note: depending on the regex implementation `[` must also be escaped

Comment: @grexter89 Fixed, it should be just fine for most RegExp engines.

Answer (score 0):

```
[\(\)\{\}\[\]\]*
```

Will catch all those characters.
Depending on your programming language and on the way you plan to handle this.
You can replace/remove these characters or give a message to the user.